# How to send email to Users who have same interest (Insterts_Users) as category type of Treatment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, actionmailer

I want to email users every time a new treatment that is under the category they are interested in is added.

I have a join table `interests_users` which is holds a `user_id` and a `interest_id`. When a user signs up he/she checks the boxes they are interested in i.e Face, Body etc. Treatments are submitted under the same headings so they can be compared to interests.

What kind of query do I need to write in order that ever time a new treatment is saved users who share the same interest as the category type of treatment get an email?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `create` action for `TreatmentsController` you can iterate over the users using find_by_sql and an appropariate sql command, getting all records that match the interest.  Then us a Mailer method as described here ... http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

The iteration might look like...

```
if @treatment.save
  interest = Interest.find_by(name: @treatment.category)
  if interest
    User.find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM users
                    INNER JOIN interests_users ON clients.id = interests_users.client_id
                    WHERE interests_users.interest_id = ?", interest.id).each do |user|
      AppMailer.send_notification(user, @treatment).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have my applications mailer set up. However when I did what you said to my treatments controller I am getting an error of 'uninitialized constant TreatmentsController::InterestUser'

Comment: Do you have a model for the interests_user or is it just a join table not defined in the app?

Comment: Or is it called "InterestsUser"" ?

Comment: No model just a join table. I have two other seperate tables called User and Interest

Comment: Hi, ok, since we don't have a Model to reference I've changed it to SQL.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go and report back. Also, what is clients.id?

Comment: Getting the error 'undefined method interest_id for #<Treatment:0x9778338>' now. Shouldn't the sql compare against the category variable? I changed 'interest_id' to 'treatment.catgory' and now it is giving the error 'undefined method `map' for "Face":String' . Face is one of the interests and also one of the treatments categorys

Comment: So, wait, do the treatments belong to `Interest` or are you saying the treatment category is just a string that's the same as the interest name?

Comment: No treatment and Interest have no direct relationship. Category is a string of treatment

Comment: It would be a better app if you could create a many-to-one relationship from treatment to interest, but we can work with what we've got.  What is the field in Interest that you want to match against category.  Is it the interest `name` field?

Comment: Yeah the field in interest I want to compare is name. So name (in Interest) against category (in Treatment). Thanks for the feedback thus far

Comment: Ok, answer revised.  Cheers  - Steve

Comment: Thanks for the revised solution but I am still getting a mapping error 'undefined method `map' for 1:Fixnum' . The values for categorys are a preset of 5, that can be picked from a dropdown by the way.